# Resizing responsive page width from 640px to 1117px in IE11 gives incorrect alignment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, media-queries

I have created the following responsive page here: http://asapuat1.bigredsky.com/mjb_v2.htm?cid=290&jbid=184

For the widths 640px to 1117px i have a 2 by 2 layout with 1 spacer div on the top and bottom rows to ensure correct alignment. Margins on input fields are set to %'s and the input fields themselves have a % width also, with a max-width of 280px.

All this works fine in Firefox, and Chrome, but in IE11 as the width is re-sized by dragging the browser window the vertical alignment changes, and the input fields are no longer vertically aligned correctly.

I suspect the spacer divs may be causing the issue, display on them when required is set to inline-block and when not required set to none.

Strangely when i encounter the issue switching off default css box-sizing: inherit via developer tools fixes, but re-size the window again and the issue still occurs

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by using margin values in pixels on input fields instead of percentages and having css only for IE 11:

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:69.75em) and (min-width:55em) and     (-ms-high-contrast:none)
input[type='text'], input#mjb-ico-search, 
#topSpacer1, #bottomSpacer1, #topSpacer2, #bottomSpacer2,   #middleSpacer1,    #middleSpacer2, select {
margin: 20px 44px;
}
}
```